# Adding two 8-bit two's complement binary numbers

Tags: binary, numbers, addition

What is the result (in 8-bit binary) of adding the two 8-bit two's complement numbers `10111011` and `11010101` and how would you go about calculating that?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably something any decent programming calculator can tell you but, assuming it wraps at eight bits, this is the result.

```
              [ hex,unsigned,signed]
     10111011 [0xBB,     187,   -69]
+    11010101 [0xD5,     213,   -43]
     --------
= (1)10010000 [0x90,     144,  -112]
```

You can do this process manually as follows:

```
set carry to zero
for each position starting at right side, progressing left:
    set sum to carry
    add bit from position in first number to sum
    add bit from position in second number to sum
    if sum is greater than one:
        subtract two from sum
        set carry to one
    else
        set carry to zero
    end if
    store sum to position of result
end for
```

Comment: ...and if present the overflow bit will be set. ;)

Comment: I had to manually add the overflow bit. After `end for` I add `result[0] = carry`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @James, if you only have 8 bits, that's usually bits 0 thru 7, so putting `carry` into `result[0]` is wrong. And, if your bits are 1 thru 8, the presence of `result[0]` means you have _nine_ bits, not eight. Usually what happens is the result will wrap around and the final value in carry will indicate this.

Answer (score 0):

The nice thing about two's complement is that you don't need to know whether you have signed or unsigned numbers. Just take the binary representation, add, and discard the overflow bit. If you've left the range of representable numbers, well, tough luck. But adding two negative numbers and getting a positive one should raise suspicion.

On a practical note: Do *not* try to guard against overflow in C by asking things like

```
a = b+c;
if (((b > 0) && (a < c)) || ((b < 0) && (a > c))) {
  ...
}
```

This would probably work in standard debug builds, but C (and C++) compilers are allowed to optimize this check away. (It is more often seen for unsigned arithmetic, `if (a >= (a+b)) { ... }`, and `gcc -Wall` will warn that it knows that to be false. Which is fine, since the C standard says that overflow is undefined behavior anyway.)

I don't know what the situation is like in other languages with limited-range integer types.